# image placeholder doesn't work the same as in Angular 1

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to show a placeholder image using Angular 2.

In Angular 1 we can use `ng-src` and do this for example:

```
<img src="img/placeholder.jpg" ng-src="{{actualone.img}}">
```

But I'm not sure what's the right way to do this in Angular 2.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: [Is this what you want ?](http://plnkr.co/edit/tEauAaPyyZO9UFZZsWns?p=preview)

Comment: @Abdulrahman exactly! Update the answer and I'll vote it. Thanks!

Comment: I am updating the answer, please don't accept it for a day or two because I think may be someone else could have a better way.

Answer (score 4):

One of my favorite shorthands in javascript is the or operator `||`

You can use it like: `var someVar = var1 || var2`. `someVar` will have the value of `var1` unless it's `undefined`, then it will have the value of `var2`.

So, in your situation, you can bind the `src` property to `imageUrl || placeholderUrl`

```
<img [src]="imageUrl || placeholderUrl| />
```

[Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QUnXBcMavEEt4dLjZ7s0?p=preview)

### Update

For having a placeholder above the image until it finishes loading.
I have achieved it with the following way:

```
<img (load)="$event.target.src=imageUrl" src="imageUrl" [src]="placeholderImage" />
```

#### Disclaimer:

I am not positive this "hack" will work in all browsers and/or will continue working in future angular2 releases.

#### Explanation:

First we set an initial url to `src` property, it will start loading automatically. Then, angular will do the binding to `[src]` which we will set to a placeholder image, then after the original image we assigned to `src` finishes loading. `img` will fire an `onLoad` event, we catch the event and reassign the `src` to the original image.

[Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FGE4PQpPeM525YIYHZD3?p=preview)

Comment: I don't think this is what I need because I need to remove the placeholder once the `imageUrl` loads. All my items have an image, but I want to show a default one in the meanwhile the actual is loading. Thanks!

Comment: Abdulrahman's code should do just what you need. While the imageUrl is null, the placeholderUrl will be used. As soon as imageUrl is not null (after it loads), the [src] property will become the imageUrl. The placeholderUrl will no longer be shown.

Comment: @mcissel I guess what mati wants is that both imageUrl and placeHolder will have actual non-null urls. But the placeholder is shown until the browser finishes loading the actual image from imageUrl. to prevent the user from seeing the image half loaded

Comment: @mcissel the problem is that I'm seeing an empty space and then the images start loading but slow. I have a list with 10 items.

Comment: can we add two `src` on single image ? great point of using or `||` in angular2 expression. +1.

Comment: @PardeepJain we are not adding two. We are adding `src` and then angular will replace it with the bound value in `[src]` while the original url in `src` is loading. Once it's finishes loading, the image will be cached so we can change the `src` back and the image will appear instantly.